# Why were canards added to some variants of the Dassault Mirage III?

Tags: canard, dassault-mirage-iii

[Mirage III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Mirage_III) offshoots like [Kfir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAI_Kfir) made by [Israel Aircraft Industries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Aerospace_Industries):

[image: Kfir]

or [Cheetah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_Cheetah) converted by South-African manufacturer [Atlas Aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_Aircraft_Corporation):

[image: Cheetah]

both have canards.

The original [Mirage III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Mirage_III) designed by French manufacturer [Dassault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Aviation) has no canards:

[image: Mirage III]

What is the reason for such addition in variants?

---

[Source](http://copy-cats.work/aircraft02/dassault-mirage-iii-france-iai-kfir-israel-atlas-cheetah) for all pictures.

Comment: I guess a better question would be what was so compelling to _add_ them on the derivative aircraft. Explaining a lack of something may be difficult: if the aircraft performs as designed to, why add more complexity? Engineers don't (usually) add complex stuff just for fun.

Comment: Probably for maneuverability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original delta Mirage was designed as an interceptor, basically to get there as soon as possible and try to stop a threat such as a nuclear bomber.  Speed was important above all else (except of course having enough stability to fly, where deltas also excel).

Canards are added for maneuverability for use as a point defender. As range is not critical for this task, the design remains viable today, but is being supplemented with stealth.

Many of the older reconnaissance/interceptors, such as the A-12/SR71 and the F15 Eagle, are still among the fastest ever flown.

Comment: and of course there was an idea to add winglets to the F-15 but it didn't make it past the state of a few (maybe even a single) technology demonstrator.

Comment: Also one could add that improved computer control (relaxed stability) allowed them to added as upgrades to older airframe designs.  Their effect on top speed would make an interesting study.

Answer (score -2):

Because nose has heavy radar inside , the nose down at Mach tuck at supersonic is done by the canard

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up that as the reason they were added? I'm not saying it isn't, but let's have proof, please.